# Generating html with CFSaveContent, images don't display

Tags: image, coldfusion, cfmail

I'm trying to use `cfsavecontent` to send an html page (with CSS formatting). However, when I send the variable via `cfmail`,  everything arrives fine, except the images.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="YourImg">
   <table class="table_css">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p> your image is this:</p>
                <img src="/imgs/image.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</cfsavecontent>


<cfmail from="email@hotmail.com" to="email@gmail.com" subject="test email" type="html">
    test:
    <br /><br /><br />
    #YourImg#
    <br /><br /><br />
</cfmail>
```

This shows me the HTML table, formatted with the CSS, but the image looks like it is missing.  Can anybody explain why?

Comment: When you want to embed images in HTML email, you can simply provide the absolute URL. So the `src` attribute would look like `http://somedomain.com/imgs/image/jpg` instead of `/imgs/image.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

`<cfsavecontent>` only saves the generated markup in between the tag into a string.  You can `<cfdump var="#YourImg#">` and see for yourself.

`<cfdocument>` can capture the image, but into a pdf file. Doc @ https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html

To attach files to the email, please look into `<cfmailparam>` @ https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmailparam.html

> Example 2: This view-only example displays an image in the body of an
>   HTML message.
>
> ```
> <cfmail type="HTML"
>   to = "#form.mailto#"
>   from = "#form.mailFrom#"
>   subject = "Sample inline image"> 
>     <cfmailparam file="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web.gif"
>       disposition="inline"
>       contentID="image1"> 
> <p>There should be an image here</p> 
> <img src="cid:image1"> 
> <p>After the picture</p> 
> </cfmail>
> ```